# LDAP Path And Permissions To Query Local User Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, active-directory

I am working on a web application, ASP.NET, C#.  Users are required to log in using an account **local** to the machine the app is running on, which I'll call "cyclops" for this example.  I want the app to be able to query the local directory of users and groups to determine what groups the user is in.  The code looks something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://cyclops/Users", "SomeServiceAccount",
    "SvcAcctP@$$word", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
entry.RefreshCache();
// Etc.
```

My two problems are:

1. That's pretty clearly not the correct path to use, but my research
   and experimentation hasn't found the right answer.  [This MSDN
   article talks about local paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but doesn't fill in the blanks.
   Do I use "LDAP://cyclops/Users", "WinNT://localhost/Users",
   "WinNT://cyclops/cn=Users"?
2. As you can see, I'm providing the
   credentials of a local service account.  That account needs
   permission to access the local directory, but I have no idea where
   to set those permissions.  Is it a specific file somewhere?  Does
   the account need to be a member of a particular group?

My experimentation has produced many errors: "The group name could not be found.", "The provider does not support searching...", "The server is not operational.", "Unknown error (0x80005004)", etc.

Thank you for your time...
-JW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinNT requires the following format

```
WinNT://<domain/server>/<object name>,<object class>
```

To get groups of a given user, use

```
using (DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./UserAccount,user"))
{
    foreach(object group in (IEnumerable)user.Invoke("Groups",null)) 
    { 
        using(DirectoryEntry g = new DirectoryEntry(group))
        {
            Response.Write(g.Name);
        }
    } 
}
```

where

- UserAccount is a name of required user.
- dot stands for current machine (you can replace it with cyclops or use  Environment.MachineName)
- user credentials ("SomeServiceAccount", "SvcAcctP@$$word") might be required, depends on setup

To get users in a particular group, use

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./Users,group")) 
{
    foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)entry.Invoke("Members"))
    {
        using(DirectoryEntry m = new DirectoryEntry(member))
        {
            Response.Write(m.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

where

- Users is a name of group

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying the second method, using the path "WinNT://./Client Users,group".  The error I'm now getting is "System.NotSupportedException: The provider does not support searching and cannot search WinNT://./Client Users,group."  This happens after I set a filter of "sAMAccountName=jsmith" and invoke FindAll().  Is this a permissions problem, or do I need to flip a bit in the configuration, or...?

Comment: You cannot mix WinNT and LDAP providers. There is no search by sAMAccountName in WinNT. If you need groups of jsmith you shoud use the first example, not the second one.

Comment: Using the first example has solved my problem, with the caveat that the site is extremely slow.  The slowness could be entirely unrelated, however, so I'm going to call this solved.

Comment: You can try to use PrincipalContext or query LDAP to see if it will work faster. Examples: http://forums.asp.net/t/1971340.aspx http://forums.asp.net/t/1611592.aspx