# How to get the IADsGroup object for a group in the domain using ADsGetObject?

Tags: windows, winapi, active-directory, ldap

### Short Version

How do i get the `IADsGroup` interface of the group **`STACKOVERFLOW\ITOps`**?

### Long Version

I am trying to get ahold of the [`IADsGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsgroup) interface for a group in the domain using the [**ADsGetObject** function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/binding-with-getobject-and-adsgetobject).

The only information i have:

- **GroupName**: e.g. `ITOps`
- **DomainName**: e.g. `STACKOVERFLOW`

The function takes an [LDAP path to an object:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsgetobject)

```
HRESULT ADsGetObject(
  [in]  LPCWSTR lpszPathName,
  [in]  REFIID  riid,
  [out] VOID    **ppObject
);
```

The real difficulty is in coming up with the actual **LDAP path** for a **group** in the **domain**. For example:

- `LDAP://STACKOVERFLOW/ITOps` *fails* *("An invalid dn syntax has been specified")*
- `LDAP://CN=ITOps,DN=STACKOVERFLOW` *fails* 0x80072020 *("An operations error occurred")*
- `LDAP://CN=ITOps,DC=STACKOVERFLOW` *fails* 0x8007202B *("A referral was returned from the server")*

### The question

Given:

- a group name (e.g. "ITOps")
- a domain name (e.g. "STACKOVERFLOW")

How do i get the `IADsGroup` interface of the group **STACKOVERFLOW\ITOps**?

### Bonus Reading

- MSDN: [Binding With GetObject and ADsGetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/binding-with-getobject-and-adsgetobject)
- MSDN: [ADsGetObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsgetobject)
- MSDN: [LDAP ADsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath)
- MSDN: [Binding to an Object Using a SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/binding-to-an-object-using-a-sid)
- MSDN: [Example Code for Getting the Distinguished Name of the Domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/example-code-for-getting-the-distinguished-name-of-the-domain)
- Serverfault: [get AD group path in the domain/tree](https://serverfault.com/questions/788418/get-ad-group-path-in-the-domain-tree)
- [LDAP path to server and a user group](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/276956-ldap-path-server-user-group)
- [Proper Syntax for an LDAP Path](https://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web%20WIL%7EExtenders/ADSI%20Proper%7ESyntax%7Efor%7Ean%7ELDAP%7EPath.txt)
- Stackoverflow: [LDAP Path And Permissions To Query Local User Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808451/ldap-path-and-permissions-to-query-local-user-directory)
- MSDN: [WinNT ADsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/winnt-adspath)
- [WinNT vs. LDAP](https://www.rlmueller.net/WinNT_LDAP.htm)
- MSDN: Glossary [WinNT](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16757.active-directory-glossary.aspx#WinNT): *"Windows NT namespace provider, supporting the Windows NT SAM account database. The WinNT provider can also be used to access Active Directory, but it exposes it as a flat namespace."*
- [C language function:ADsGetObject sample codes](http://www.it-word.net/api/capi/en-us/ADsGetObject.html)
- MSDN: [Unsupported IADsUser Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/unsupported-iadsuser-properties) *("To obtain and/or modify these properties, use the LDAP provider")*
- MSDN: [WinNT Custom User Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/winnt-custom-user-properties) *("The WinNT provider makes available the following custom properties for the User class")*

Comment: I think you want `DC` instead of `DN`.

Comment: @Luke Added your suggestion to the question.

Comment: `WinNT://STACKOVERFLOW/ITOps,group`? (SAM style names only)

Comment: Use AD Explorer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer

Comment: @Luke Stackoverflow is a programming web-site. That comment would be more applicable for Superuser or Serverfault.

Comment: @Anders Unfortunately the `WinNT` schema is very different from the `LDAP` schema; properties available through LDAP (e.g. `objectGUID`) are not available through WinNT. (MSDN: [Unsupported IADsUser Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/unsupported-iadsuser-properties))

Comment: But if WinNT works you can NameTranslate to find the ldap syntax?

Comment: @Anders What is an example of this? I assume you mean [`IADsNameTranslate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsnametranslate-init)? What am i translating from what to what? Also, seems like i'm going down the road now of ***three*** round-trips; rather than 1.

Comment: From Winnt to ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779. I was merely suggesting this to find the syntax, not to do it every time.

Comment: @IanBoyd You're asking for the format of the LDAP path. AD Explorer will give you the format of the LDAP path. I'm assuming the example you're giving in this question is not the actual domain configuration you're dealing with, so all I can do is teach you to fish.

Comment: @Luke Unfortunately, given a **domainName** and a **groupName**, that in no way matches the corresponding **disginguishedName** of the group. Getting the `distinguishedName` ***IS*** the problem.

Comment: @Anders I know full well that a group named `STACKOVERFLOW\ITOps` will have a distingushed name of `cn=ITOps,dc=stackoverflow,dc=com`. Except it could also be `cn=ITOps,dc=stackoverflow,dc=gce,dc=gms,dc=ent,dc=local`; because all i know of the domain name is the `STACKOVERFLOW` name, rather than the other `stackoverflow.gce.gms.local` domain name. You're suggesting i get the `dn` by knowing the `dn` already. Except that's the problem; i don't know the `dn`; i only know `domain name` and `group name`, and those are not LDAP things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several unique identifiers for objects in AD, and they can't all be used in the same way, which makes things a bit confusing.

This is documentation you need for that path (which you already linked to): [LDAP ADsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath)

That shows that the LDAP path should look like:

```
LDAP://HostName[:PortNumber][/DistinguishedName]
```

The `HostName`, `PortNumber` and `DistinguishedName` are all optional, depending on what you're trying to do. If you need to bind to a specific object - which is what you're trying to do - then the `DistinguishedName` is mandatory.

The distinguished name is the `distinguishedName` attribute of the object, which is why Luke suggested that you use AD Explorer to browse to the object in your directory and inspect the value of the `distinguishedName` attribute. The DN is a concatenation of the common name (CN), each organizational unit (OU) and the domain DNS name (e.g. stackoverflow.com) split into each of its domain components (DC). That will look something like this:

```
CN=ITOps,OU=Groups,DC=stackoverflow,DC=com
```

The format `STACKOVERFLOW\ITOps` is the domain's short name (officially called the NetBIOS name), combined with the `sAMAccountName` attribute of the object. This format is often used for authenticating with user accounts, but cannot be used in an LDAP path.

If you're hard coding this group into your code, then just look up the `distinguishedName` and use that. If you will be given the `STACKOVERFLOW\ITOps` format by the user and need to bind to it, then you can either:

1. Use [`IADsNameTranslate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsnametranslate) to translate from `ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4` to `ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779`, or
2. Perform a search on the domain using the search filter `(sAMAccountName=ITOps)`. To perform an LDAP search in C++, see the documentation for [`IDirectorySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/searching-with-idirectorysearch). You still have to provide an LDAP path for the search, but you can just provide the domain DNS name (e.g. `LDAP://stackoverflow.com`). That allows you to specify which attributes it wants you to return, so you can tell it that you want the `distinguishedName`. Or if your purpose in binding to the object is to read some other attribute, then you can specify those attributes and read those attributes from the search result, and then you can skip the next step of binding directly to the object.

It seems like you plan to use C++, but you didn't specifically say that. Are you using C++?

Comment: `IADsNameTranslate` was the best option. I'd already spent 14 hours trying to get `IDirectorySearch` to work - i think it was an ABI issue. Either way, it seems like *searching* the directory is the correct, supported, and intended way to get ahold of an object from the remote database. That is *probably* what `IADsNameTranslate` is doing; but does it much better. And i'm not using C++, but i am inside another natively compiled strongly statically typed language.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the `dn` of the domain then you can obtain it via [`rootDSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/rootdse)